# Stop executing function after one time Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, counter

I'm working on some counters in JavaScript and I came a cross a problem with big numbers that needed seperators. So I rewrote a part of the JavaScript just for the counter that needed the seperators. I created a seperate function that created the seperator. I also build that the Counters should start with Page Offset on scroll. This is my full JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var element_position = $("#projecten-in-beeld").offset().top;
        $(window).on("scroll", function () {
            var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
            var scroll_pos_test = element_position;

            if (y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) {
                $(".fact-inhoud").each(function () {
                    var $this = $(this),
                        countTo = $this.attr("data-count");

                    $({ countNum: $this.text() }).animate(
                        {
                            countNum: countTo,
                        },

                        {
                            duration: 3000,
                            easing: "linear",
                            step: function () {
                                $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
                            },
                            complete: function () {
                                $this.text(this.countNum);
                                //alert('finished');
                            },
                        }
                    );
                }); // end data-count
                $(".fact-inhoud2").each(function () {
                    var $this = $(this),
                        countTo = $this.attr("data-count2");

                    $({ countNum: $this.text() }).animate(
                        {
                            countNum: countTo,
                        },

                        {
                            duration: 5000,
                            easing: "linear",
                            step: function () {
                                $this.text(commaSeparateNumber(Math.floor(this.countNum)));
                            },
                            complete: function () {
                                $this.text(commaSeparateNumber(this.countNum));
                                //alert('finished');
                            },
                        }
                    );
                }); // end data-count
            }
        });
    });

    function commaSeparateNumber(val) {
        while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())) {
            val = val.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, "$1" + "." + "$2");
        }
        return val;
    }
</script>
```

It is working great and the counters starts to run when I am at the DIV where the counters are. When I scroll furder when I am on the counters they stop and continuous counting where they stopped. Only the new Counter that is using the 'commaSeparateNumber' function for the seperators starts over from zero when I scroll.

How can I for some reason kill this function that is only excutes once and not every time I scroll again?

Comment: You are using the Windows "onScroll" so it executes every time you scroll...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve a similar result using a boolean flag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var isExecuted = false;
        var element_position = $("#projecten-in-beeld").offset().top;
        $(window).on("scroll", function () {
             if (!isExecuted) {
                 // Your code
                 isExecuted = true;
             }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for the response. The counters should not start on document ready. They should start when somebody scrolls down to the div "#projecten-in-beeld". From that point the counters should start running. With the current code, they do. Only when scroll again the Counter that uses the function for the seperators: "commaSeparateNumber". Starts over again from zero. All the other run fine but that one starts over and I know it has something to do with this function: "commaSeparateNumber" but how can I stop it from running after one time and not everytime I scroll furder?

Comment: You can do something simple with a boolean flag.
You pre-set it at document ready to false "isExecuted = false" and then when your code is ran onscroll you set it to true and check if !isExecuted before running your code. I have added an example in my answer, please check.

Comment: thank you very much! This was just the push that I needed! Made it work!